# Swap dates if from_date is greater than to_date

Tags: php, date, swap, strtotime

I've two dates from_date and to_date. How to swap the two dates if the from_date is greater than the to_date. Here is the code I've tried. Thank You!

```
$from_date = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['from']);
$to_date = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['to']);

if(strtotime($from_date) > strtotime($to_date)) {
    $temp_date = $to_date;
    $from_date = $to_date;
    $to_date = $temp_date;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong logic for swapping. You are not saving value of `from_date` before changing its value to `to_date`.

```
if(strtotime($from_date) > strtotime($to_date)) {
    $temp_date = $from_date;
    $from_date = $to_date;
    $to_date = $temp_date;
}
```

Comment: to accept the answer we need to wait at least 15 minutes. Now I've accepted the answer.